# Amazon sp_api - Get Orders Address with Restricted Data Token

Tags: python, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to get the Buyer info from the Amazon sp_api, especially from the get_orders call. We now got the authorization to request a RDT but I don't really understand how to implement this in my Python script.

I found something like this:

```
res = Tokens(credentials=credentials, marketplace=Marketplaces.DE).create_restricted_data_token(path='/orders/v0/orders/xxx/address')
print(res)
```

But I get this error every time:

> [{'code': 'InvalidInput', 'message': 'Empty target resource argument found', 'details': ''}]